# Count two independent group by clauses accross a three table join

Tags: mysql, sql

Count relations independently across a three table join joins.

When joining two tables I know how to use count and group by clauses to count the number of times the id of one table appears as a relation in another, but cannot figure out how to count the number two such relations with two tables independently.

Consider the three tables A, B and C with the following sample data

```
Table A         Table B          Table C

|id|           |id|A_id|         |id|A_id|
 --             -- ----           -- ----
|1 |           |1 |1   |         |1 |1   |
|2 |           |2 |1   |         |2 |3   |
|3 |           |3 |3   |         |3 |2   |
|4 |           |3 |4   |         |4 |3   |
```

In both tables B and C, the column A_id cannot be NULL, but in table C, column B_id can be NULL.

I want a query such that for every entry in table A I will get the number of related entries in table B and also the number of related entries in table C. For the above data I would want a query that returned the following:

```
A_id|Count(B)|Count(C)
---- -------- --------
|1  |2       |1
|2  |0       |1
|3  |1       |2
|4  |1       |0
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to `COUNT` them in a subquery.

```
SELECT  a.ID, 
        IFNULL(b.`COUNT(B)`, 0) `COUNT(B)`,
        IFNULL(c.`COUNT(C)`, 0) `COUNT(C)`
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
          SELECT bb.A_ID, COUNT(*) `COUNT(B)`
          FROM   tableB bb
          GROUP BY A_ID
        ) b ON a.id = b.A_ID
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
          SELECT cc.A_ID, COUNT(*) `COUNT(C)`
          FROM   tableC cc
          GROUP BY A_ID
        )c ON a.ID = c.A_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e05a8/15)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little simpler than it initially sounds, although it requires the use of sub-selects:

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(b.count, 0), COALESCE(c.count, 0)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, COUNT(*) as count
           FROM b
           GROUP BY a_id) b
on b.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, COUNT(*) as count
           FROM c
           GROUP BY a_id) c
on c.a_id = a.id
```

Grouping needs to be performed *before* joining to `a`, because you end up having duplicates in some of your child tables, which can throw off your results.

Answer (score 0):

If combinations of (B.id, A_id) and (C.id, A_id) are unique, you could use this:

```
select
  A.ID, count(distinct B.id), count(distinct C.id)
from
  A left join B on a.ID = B.A_ID
  left join C on a.ID=C.A_ID
group by A.id
```

but if they are not, you have to do the counts using subqueries.

Comment: @jw. i'm counting `distinct B.id` and `distinct C.id` so this will give the correct result, unless there are duplicated combinations of (id,A_id) in table B or in table C

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried it out and whilst it works for my data, its an extremely slow query. All my id columns are primary keys and I've got indexes on the A_id columns in tables B and C. I don't know if this is the query or my poor indexing?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using subqueries came to me whilst I was in bed last night, so I'm pleased that's what others have suggested. I think that my query is simpler than the others suggested so above and seems to run very quickly, but I would appreciate input on whether my query is actually any better/worse than those already given.

```
SELECT 
    TableA.id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableB where TableB.A_id = TableA.id) countB,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableC where TableC.A_id = TableA.id) countC
FROM TableA;
```

Comment: I'm counting distinct, and distinct could be slow sometimes. I am not sure why your query is faster than the others, but it looks good to me!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that my query was faster than the other, it's the same speed as the others, but I think its a lot simpler and more readable. I'm not great a writing SQL and I was hoping that someone could give sound reasons as to which of the suggested queries is the best, so that I learn how to write better queries myself.

Comment: I agree that your solution it's the most simpler and easier to read, and it is correct. I suspect it could be slow, but my query could also be slow because it uses distinct, while your query doesn't...even the ones with group by are nice solutions, it's not easy to tell which one is the best... all of them work, and all of them uses different techniques... sometimes you can choose the technique you want, sometimes you have to use only one, but i think it's important to understand how all of them work!